# Getting PhpED to treat ctp files like php files

Tags: php, syntax, ctp, phped

Hi I want PhpED to treat ctp files like PHP files. So it will do all the syntax highlighting and auto-complete functionality you get when coding within a PHP file. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In phpED go to Tools->Settings->Associations and add .ctp under the PHP type.

Comment: Thanks a lot! There had to be a simple way to do it!